# Cannot delete rows from a table that is in many-to-many relation with the other table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities with a many-to-many relationship.
**

```
public class Appointment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private LocalDateTime actionDateTime;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_appointments",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="appointment_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id")})
    private Set<AppUser> participants = new HashSet<>();
}

public class AppUser implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    private int rating;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "participants", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Set<Appointment> appointments = new HashSet<>();
}
```

How how do I delete from Appointment? Every time I try it I see the following error:

> 18:43:23  `delete from appointments where appointments.id = 1`
> Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails `` (`beauty_salon`.`users_appointments`, CONSTRAINT `FKe4fn9rrveg7s7ff17fxnwt51d` FOREIGN KEY (`appointment_id`) REFERENCES `appointments` (`id`)) ``  0.000 sec

If I reverse engineer the database that I've created and then forward engineer it to see the code, here's what we would see:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema beauty_salon
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema beauty_salon
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `beauty_salon` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ;
USE `beauty_salon` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `beauty_salon`.`appointments`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beauty_salon`.`appointments` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `action_date_time` DATETIME(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `beauty_salon`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beauty_salon`.`users` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` INT NOT NULL,
  `role` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `UK_r43af9ap4edm43mmtq01oddj6` (`username` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 5
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `beauty_salon`.`users_appointments`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beauty_salon`.`users_appointments` (
  `appointment_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `user_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`appointment_id`, `user_id`),
  INDEX `FK1mwwyjbcdbqsvock8n7quafhv` (`user_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK1mwwyjbcdbqsvock8n7quafhv`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `beauty_salon`.`users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FKe4fn9rrveg7s7ff17fxnwt51d`
    FOREIGN KEY (`appointment_id`)
    REFERENCES `beauty_salon`.`appointments` (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: You can try `orphanRemoval = true` `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)`

Comment: Show this 3 tables DDLs (how does they looks like in MySQL).

Comment: Carefully consider whether you really want to hard delete parent data through this process

Comment: @Akina, I've added the SQL code to my post.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm trying to delete a row from Appointment, and it simply won't let me. Not sure what you mean. However, I can easily delete rows from AppUser.

Comment: `FKe4fn9rrveg7s7ff17fxnwt51d` have no ON DELETE action. Set it to some acrtion - to SET NULL, for example...

Comment: @Akina I've commented out the OnDelete annotation, the result is still the same. So it must be something with the cascades, right?

Comment: The fiddle with provided structures added into the answer. Investigate.

Answer (score 0):

In general - if you need to delete some entity in M:N relation then you simply remove the rows for this entity from its table. Cascade actions of foreign keys (which must be correctly defined) performs all needed additional operations.

[<kbd>**Example**</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ceb7e59c958948e7288bdc53af0cf027)

Remember - none rows will be deleted from another entity table - even when no related records in adjacent table exists after deletion. You must delete entity rows explicitly anycase (for example, use daily service event procedure) if needed.

---

[<kbd>**The fiddle**</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f1b0d2913b397efac0f326e4f9cb2e7f) with DDLs provided.